# Android 12+ BLE Bytes are different

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I developed a small App in **Kotlin** which Scans for nearby **BLE**-Beacons using `bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback)`.
That works pretty well (the scanning/discovery part).

After testing my App on **Android 10**, **Android 12** and on **Android 13** I found out, that the `ScanResult.scanRecord.bytes` Array is completely different for the same BLE-Beacon (same Device Name and same Device MAC-Address) on **Android 12** and **Android 13**.
I have full Access to the "correct" Byte within **Android 10** which enables me to read *Major*, *Minor*, *UUID *and a **Customly Added** *BatteryLevel*. The BatteryLevel is just an additional Byte which can range from 00 to 64 (00 = 0% and 64 = 100%).
Within **Android 12+** I get an Byte-Array which only contains the MAC-Address (that's what I could figure out after converting each Byte to Hexdecimal). There are more Bytes present than the MAC-Address but these are unknown to me (mentioned Byte's don't resemble UUID, Major, Minor or the BatteryLevel).

So basically my issue is within getting the same amount of Data from Android 12+ as I get from Android 10. That's why I guess that the `bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback)` need to be adjusted for Android 12+ to work properly or I need to change the way I'm collecting the Data for each `ScanResult` for Android 12+.

I would appreciate any kind of Help.

I've looked at the [Android BLE Doc](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/ble?hl=en) but there is nowhere written, that the `ScanResult.scanRecord.bytes` Array changes from **Android 12** onwards. There is also no mention of any different Approach for **Android 12+** other than [Bluetooth Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) which need to be set for **Android 12+**.

I've looked at the Byte-Array, converted it to Hex and searched for patterns if UUID, Major, Minor or BatteryLevel are to be found unfortunately to no avail. Searching for BLE tutorials on YT doesn't helped either. There are mostly Theoretical Vids or Vids for BLE on **Android 11** and below.

Code for BLE-Beacon Scan:`bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback)`

*Android Manifest Permissions*:

```
<!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <!-- Include "neverForLocation" only if you can strongly assert that
         your app never derives physical location from Bluetooth scan results. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

Code within `ScanCallback onScanResult`:

```
if(result.scanRecord?.bytes != null){
val sb = StringBuilder()
for (b in result.scanRecord!!.bytes) {
sb.append(String.format("%02X", b))
}
val trimmedSb = sb.toString().trim()  
if(trimmedSb.endsWith("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"))  {  
return // useless data  
}  


if(trimmedSb.length >= 61){  
  if(trimmedSb.endsWith("0000")){  
     batteryLevel = -1  
  }else{  
     batteryLevel = trimmedSb.substring(IntRange(60, 61)).toInt(16)  
  }  
}  

if(trimmedSb.length >= 50){
val uuid_first = trimmedSb.substring(18,26)
val uuid_second = trimmedSb.substring(26, 30) 
val uuid_third = trimmedSb.substring(30,34)
val uuid_fourth = trimmedSb.substring(34, 38)  
val uuid_fith = trimmedSb.substring(38,50)      
uuid = "$uuid_first-$uuid_second-$uuid_third-$uuid_fourth-$uuid_fith"  
}

if(trimmedSb.length >= 54){
major = trimmedSb.substring(50, 54).padStart(4,'0')
}

if(trimmedSb.length >= 58){
minor = trimmedSb.substring(54, 58).padStart(4,'0')
}
```

Comment: If you scanning for a BLE beacon, remove the assertion android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" in scan permission.

Comment: Removing the "neverForLocation" seems to "break" my BLE-Scan. If I remove it, not a single BLE-Beacon shows up. If I add it in again, at least BLE-Beacons show up on Scan.

Comment: By asserting that the scan is "neverForLocation" you are saying that you are not looking for a Beacon device. For scanning a beacon device, you should not add the "neverForLocation" attribute, instead, you need to add location permission in the manifest and turn ON location.

Comment: That fixed my issue... Thanks a lot^^ Please use your comment as answer.
I forgot to turn on "Location" on Android 12+ Devices...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By asserting that the scan is "neverForLocation" you are saying that you are not looking for a Beacon device. For scanning a beacon device, you should not add the "neverForLocation" attribute, instead, you need to add location permission in the manifest and turn ON location.