Android - modern BLE scanner returns different advertising data than deprecated version
When I scan for BLE devices using bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan() I receive different advertising data than the deprecated bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan().
The deprecated version returns the data I would expect, when converted to a hex string it looks like this:
0201061bff030dff015c4c38d1193201ff94f5480a2c2f8cdad800ff00000811079ecadc240ee5a9e093f3a3b50100406e00000000000000000000000000
Using the new version I get something similar but not what I'd expect at all:
0201061aff4c0002155c4c38d11932475db09489c375f6c84300bc0001c30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
The only thing I'm doing to turn the byte arrays into hex strings is calling this toHex() function on them:
fun ByteArray.toHex(): String = joinToString(separator = "") { eachByte -> "%02x".format(
eachByte
) }
How can the advertising bytes be so different? This worries me because some day the deprecated version may be removed and then my app will no longer function.
called bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()
called scanResult.toHex()
got 0201061bff030dff015c4c38d1193201ff94f5480a2c2f8cdad800ff00000811079ecadc240ee5a9e093f3a3b50100406e00000000000000000000000000
This was good.
called bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan()
called scanResult.bytes.toHex()
got 0201061aff4c0002155c4c38d11932475db09489c375f6c84300bc0001c30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
This was bad. This is the non-deprecated approach, why is it wrong?

Do you have the necessary permissions, as in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155895/android-12-ble-bytes-are-different

Welcome to Stack Overflow. To clarify: In your question, you are comparing the BLE advertising of 2 completely different devices from different manufacturers. And that there are differences there is what I would call expected behaviour. I would be worried if they were the same ;-)

If this is you, your software lacks a filter that only processes Bluetooth advertisements from devices manufactured by your company and suppresses advertisements from other devices (e.g. Apple).

Ugh thank you both, I think I was just staring at it for way too long last week. Good to know I am easily discoverable on the internet lol. An older version of our firmware was indeed advertising as Apple and contains some similar information - I didn't realize I had several devices advertising. Thank you again!
